# How to Generate a Dynamic Text in a html List

Tags: php, html

I need to generate a dynamic text in accordance with the number of data that comes from the database.

**In a html List**, I need to display the following text as example:

- GROUP A
- GROUP B
- GROUP C

If the amount of records coming from the DB is only 1000, then only one item list is displayed. 1000 records equals 1 Item list.

The text must be dynamically changed as described above.
Each text in the list is displayed for 1000 records.

The code below statically displays 11 items

I've made a few tries on the code below but still to no avail.

This code is working, but it display only the static text.

```
$return .= "<div id='test_id'><ul>";    
    // $qty = 10424 / $limit = 1000 
    // $tabs = $qty / $limit = 10,424
    $tabs = $qty/$limit; 

    for ($i=0; $i < $tabs ; $i++) 
        { 
            $start = $i * $limit + 1;
            $end = ($i + 1) * $limit;            
                $color = 'classpA';
                $message = '<small>GROUP A</small>';
                if ($i < $tab_selected) {
                    $color = 'classB';
                    $message = 'RESERVED';
                }
                $active = $i == $tab_selected ? "active" : "";

                $return .= "<li class='tab {$color} {$active}' tab-id='#tab-".$i."'>

                <span class='available {$color}_text'><small>{$message}</small></span>

                <a href='#' class='{$color}_text'>".$start." - ".min($end,$qty)."</a></li>";
             
        }    
    $return .= "</ul></div>";
```

And this is that logic that i`m trying to apply

```
$qty = 18424;
$limit = 1000;
$tabs = ($qty / $limit);

$group = $tabs / $limit;

$alphabet = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');

for($i = 0; $i < $group; $i++) {
    echo "Group {$alphabet[$i]}".'<br>';
}

echo 'Qtd Group= '.$group.' Value Var Tabs= '.$tabs;
```

`https://www.tehplayground.com/zyVzmaeYnTyyA4S9`

How can I make the magic happen?

Comment: At least you need to make a query on the db to get the $qty value. (but there is no such thing in your codes)

Comment: @KenLee, yes, I did not post the whole code. There is no query on the DB here, but as i commented, this peace of code works "static".

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is fine, just the limit to the for loop seems to be miscalculated.

Right now, for the variable `group = (qty/limit)/limit`, you have an extra division by limit here.

Whatever your need maybe for that division, you can simply use the value of `tabs` in your for loop condition, or assign it to another temporary variable its up to you.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $tabs; $i++) {
    echo "Group {$alphabet[$i]}".'<br>';
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could helps you

```
<?php

//$tabs = ($qty / $limit);
//$group = $tabs / $limit;


$alphabet   = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
$return     = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
$a          = array_chunk($return, 3);
//$a            = array_chunk($return, $limit);

$key        = 0;
$group      = array();
$r          = count($a);


foreach($alphabet as $v)
{
    if($key < $r)
    {
        if(!isset($group[$v]))
        {
            $group[$v] = array();
        }
        
        $group[$v] = $a[$key];
        
        $key++;
    }
}
```

```
print_r($group);
```

Here
https://www.tehplayground.com/bfmZOubIMdmBcjhu